# No me detecta la media query

Tags: html, css, responsive

estoy realizando una pagina de practica y la quiero hacer responsive. La cuestion es que no me reconoce la media query, todo lo que modifico antes de eso me lo toma pero las medias hace de cuenta que no existe. estan bien redactadas las propiedades y probe con "@media only screen and" y con "@media screen and" poniendole un max-width de 500px siendo la idea que cuando sea menor de 500px un menu desapareciera y apareciera otro pero en lugar de estar en linea este en bloque.
Dejo el codigo, muchas gracias.
Si es necesario dejo el HTML pero no me lo deja subir ahora.

css:

```
    .lista{
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

.nav__LI a {
    text-decoration-line:none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#c5cbd4;
    font-family: roboto;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.nav__LI{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: -1.9999999999999999999999999999px;
    border-right: : solid 2px black;
    padding: 0;
}


header{
    background-color: #2f3a4a;

}

.texto{
    margin-top: 20px;
    color:#323638;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: roboto;

}

.PrincipalPaginaUno{
    width: 1500px;
    margin-top:30px;
}

body{
    background-color: #c2cdd1;
}

aside{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-weight: 900;   
    width: 500px
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

aside h1{
    margin:1em;
}

.prod{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    text-decoration-style: none;
}

.prod:hover{
    width: 50%;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.descrip:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #323610;
}

.descrip:visited{
    color: #323680;
}

.nav__responsive-UL{
    display: block;
}}

 @media screen and (max-width: 500PX) {
    .nav__UL{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Comment: HOla Mariano, tenes un error de sintaxis. Te esta sobrando una llave en la regla `.nav__responsive-UL{
    display: block;
}}` <- esa